# Magento2 tier price on configurable products

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I have an configurable product for example T-Shirts in size small, medium and large. And all have same price and we have tier price like:
Buy 10 for 5.50 and save 10%
Buy 20 for 5.00 and save 20%

Now a customer buys 5 medium T-Shirts and 10 large. So he has total 15 articles of this T-Shirt. Default Magento is now only take tier price of 10 large T-Shirts, but not for 5 medium T-Shirts.

Is there any way - maybe an extension (did not found one yet) - to add also tier price for 5 medium T-Shirts?

Thanks!
martin

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what our extension [tier price for configurable products (M2)](https://marketplace.magento.com/customgento-module-configurable-tier-prices-m2.html) does. It updates the tier price calculation as you described and has the following additional features:

- tier price calculation across multiple variations
- updated calculation can be disabled for each configurable product
- updated calculation can be disabled for each category
- [new] tier price calculation type can be configured:

  - use the highest tier price
  - use the lowest tier price
  - use the tier price of the respective product

You can find some screenshots on our [docs page](http://docs.customgento.com/tier-prices-for-configurable-products-m2.html).

Mind that the extension only works for Magento >= 2.2 since some serious configurable product bugs have been fixed in this version.

Comment: i need to check one condition before apply tier price in configurable product while add product into cart. Have you any idea which file use for that?
currently i am use this file "magento_catalogModel/Product/Type/Price.php" but its only work with simple product.

Comment: Simon, this is your module?

Comment: @brentwpeterson exactly. This is what I meant by "our" ;-)